# What is the antonym of "dependent"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A depends on B, is A dependant, or is B dependant?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12547/a-depends-on-b-is-a-dependant-or-is-b-dependant)
>   [“Employee” is to “employer” as “dependent” is to what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/employee-is-to-employer-as-dependent-is-to-what)

A and B are two persons. When A is a *dependent* of B, what of A is B?

Comment: I suspect you mean ***dependant***, don’t you? That’s the noun. *Dependent* is an adjective.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12547/18655; http://english.stackexchange.com/q/67365/18655

Comment: Hi @Tim--I edited out the "Thanks!" at the end of your question because it doesn't add a lot of context. For more information, please see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @tchrist: Well, at my tdameritrade account, there is an item "Number of dependents". Also in 1040 form, it says "If someone can claim you as a dependent,...". What is the difference between dependant and dependent as nouns?

Comment: @Tim They’ve used the wrong word, then. Pity, that.

Comment: @tchrist: this source says dependent has the same meaning as dependant: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+dependent&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs

Comment: That’s nice. The OED says of **dependent** *adj*.: “Originally *dependant*, a. Fr. *dépendant* (14th c. in Hatzf.), pr. pple. of *dépendre* to hang down, depend: from the 16th c. often assimilated to L. *dēpendēnt-em*, and now usually so spelt, **the form in *-ant* being almost obs. in the adj., though retained in the sb., q.v.”** Yes, we know what they meant.  Yes, they used the wrong word. So?

Comment: @tchrist: What do " obs.", "sb.", "q.v." mean? I cannot parse the sentence in bold.

Comment: **obs.** is *obsolete*, **sb.** is *substantive* (read: noun), and **q.v.** is *quod vide*.

Comment: @tchrist OED seems to be giving British spelling, as one might expect. IRS is using American spelling, also as one might expect. http://grammarist.com/spelling/dependant-dependent/

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the term **provider** or the phrase **principal provider** conveys the relationship.

SUPPLEMENT: I think JLG is right that this is a duplicate (and others have suggested what I propose).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the circumstance, if A is the *dependant* of B, then B may be the *guardian* of A. As tchris noted, this would apply for a parent-child relationship, but it does not fit when referring to spouses.

Comment: With children, perhaps, but with spouses? Doesn’t seem quite right.

Comment: @tchrist - good point. Will qualify my answer.