# Something like antonym for "dependent"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, terminology, antonyms

Let's suppose I have two objects – `A` and `B`. They are a pair. I mean that we will name them considering them one logical unit.

For example: If I call `A` as "driven," then `B` will be called "leading" with reference to `A`.

Question: If I call `A` *dependent* (adj.), what should I call `B`?

Comment: There are a number of related questions, eg [77253](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77253/what-is-the-antonym-of-dependent) and [12457](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12547/a-depends-on-b-is-a-dependant-or-is-b-dependant) but they refer to dependent *people* not *things* (and consequently come up with words like *benefactor* or *supporter*, which don't seem to me to apply here.)

Comment: If you're stressing merely that B doesn't depend in any way on A, it's **independent** of A. But if you're stressing that without  B, A would fail, B is **necessary** for A.

Comment: Antonym of dependent? Independent?

Comment: Good question. Please check previous posts (use the search box above) first, before posting a question. Also, try to take some help in formulating a question in a grammatically correct way. Good Luck.

Comment: Related/ Possible Duplicate: *What is the correct word for “dependee”?* http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/what-is-the-correct-word-for-dependee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependent object would more context-appropriately be termed the

*[depender](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/depender)*

> (*programming*) An agent that depends on another agent, the *dependee*; the subject of a dependency, a dependent (used in agent-oriented programming)
>   Usage notes
>   Technical term, not widely used in software engineering outside of agent-oriented programming; the common term *dependent* is used instead. In agent-oriented programming, the antonym is *dependee*, though there is no common language equivalent (other metaphors are used instead, such as parent/child). Further, the circumlocutions “A depends on B” and “B is depended on by A” are used for clarity.

and the object on which the depender depends is termed the

*[dependee](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dependee)*

> (*programming*) An agent that is depended on by a depender, the target of a dependency (used in agent-oriented programming)
>   Usage notes
>   Technical term, not widely used in software engineering outside of agent-oriented programming but finds some use. In agent-oriented programming the antonym is *depender*, though in general usage the common term dependent is used instead. There is no common language equivalent for *dependee*, however – other metaphors are used instead, such as parent/child. The circumlocutions “A depends on B” and “B is depended on by A” are much more common in general use than “A is the depender, B is the dependee”.

src: Wikipedia

See also, related post *What is the correct word for “dependee”?* right [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/what-is-the-correct-word-for-dependee) on ELU. Especially the [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104300/14666) by EvanK.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need. But I can't upvote as I don't have scores enough.

Comment: Never mind, it's nice to be of help. Any time.