# What is the antonym of the verb "to depend"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, antonyms

I've found in this community [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/12547/68782) and [this other question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/67365/68782) mentioning the antonym of the adjective *dependent*, which is *independent*.

What I wanted to know is how to use a proper antonym *verb* for *to depend*, since there is no such a thing as *to independ*?

This would be used in a context like:

> The figures also show that the convergence behavior [independs] on the number of terms.

Comment: English doesn't have all the words we'd sometimes like.

Comment: What is the Portuguese verb, have you looked up the translation in a bilingual dictionary, and what did it say?

Comment: @RegDwigнt the portuguese verb is `independer` and the bilingual dictionary suggests to use `is independent` or `are independent` depending on the context...

Comment: Well then, that's the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As "not depend" is the opposite of "depend, "does not depend" should serve you well.

Answer (score 2):

*The figures also show that the convergence behavior "is [sufficient unto itself](http://s3.amazonaws.com/prealliance_oneclass_sample/Dq6Xxbp4ea.pdf)*".

*The figures also show that the convergence behavior "can dispense with/can do without" the number of terms*.

*The figures also show that the convergence behavior "can work on its own without" the number of terms".

Answer (score 1):

Another good possibility is to use the adjective *independent:*

> The figures also show that the convergence behavior **is independent** of the number of terms.

Comment: *Independent* takes the preposition *of*, so it should be "the convergence behaviour is independent *of* the number of terms".

Comment: @RahulNarain thank you very much for the feedback... how do you know that it takes the preposition "of"?

Comment: Sadly, there is no logical reason why it goes *dependent on* but *independent of*, but this is how prepositions are in English. You can look up usage examples in a dictionary, such as [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/independent), entry 1c(1): "independent of her parents".