# “recommends” is to “recommendation”, as “depends” is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

If BAR depends on FOO – in the sense of “BAR has FOO as a prerequisite” – I can use the term “dependency” for one end of that relationship:

> BAR has a *dependency* on FOO.

What is an equivalent, simple term for the opposite relationship:

> FOO is a *is-depended-on-by* for BAR

I'm seeking a generally-applicable answer, so *FOO* and *BAR* are just placeholders for entities.

The noun should work as one of a collection of terms, “FOO is a *recommendation* for BAR”, “FOO is a *suggestion* for BAR”.

> - BAR *suggests* FOO ⇒ FOO is a *suggestion* from BAR
> - BAR *recommends* FOO ⇒ FOO is a *recommendation* from BAR
> - BAR *depends on* FOO ⇒ FOO is a *noun-for-other-end-of-the-dependency-relation* from BAR

Note that these terms – “suggests”, “recommends”, “depends” – are not open for me to change. I am looking for the term at the other and of each of those named relations.

Examples:

> - The hockey rulebook *suggests* the Pickworth tie breaker
>     ⇒ The Pickworth tie breaker is a *suggestion* from the hockey rulebook
> - The city guidebook *recommends* the seven-day rail pass
>     ⇒ The seven-day rail pass is a *recommendation* from the city guidebook
> - The state budget *depends on* the federal tax concession
>     ⇒ The federal tax concession is a *noun-for-other-end-of-the-dependency-relation* from the state budget

What term goes in that place in the *depends*–*is-depended-on* relationship?

The answers to “[“Employee” is to “employer” as “dependent” is to what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/employee-is-to-employer-as-dependent-is-to-what)” don't apply, because those are specifically about people (and carry all the baggage of that, e.g. parent–child, sponsorship, etc.) that are not generally applicable.

The answers to “[A depends on B, is A dependant, or is B dependant?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12547/a-depends-on-b-is-a-dependant-or-is-b-dependant)” address the issue of *parts of speech*, which is not the subject of this question.

What is a noun which describes **the relationship** from the depended-on side?

Comment: This might be easier to answer if the example sentences used regular words, and were meaningful sentences. The question would also be clearer if **FOO** (which itself is not part of the question) were left out.

Comment: I'm really tempted to say that there is no general term, that the relationship must be known so that an appropriate word can be used.

Comment: I too suspect the answers will be different according to the field of study where you want to apply this. IOW, the discipline is *the determining factor* in the choice of term.

Comment: I'd suggest to change "dependency" to "requirement": `The state budget requires the federal tax concession ⇒ The federal tax concession is a requirement from the state budget` - you may also consider "needs" / "necesity".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @miltonaut suggests:

> I'm really tempted to say that there is no general term, that the relationship must be known so that an appropriate word can be used.

Thus far it seems this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

[Prerequisite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prerequisite), defined by Merriam-Webster as

> something that is necessary to an end or to the carrying out of a function

partially fits your need:

> BAR is a prerequisite for FOO.

This sentence means that in order for FOO to happen/exist, BAR is a condition that must be satisfied. It does not, however, mean that BAR and **only** BAR will allow FOO to happen/exist.

Comment: If I understand correctly, “prerequisite” is a synonym of “dependency”. That's not the question. I am seeking a word for the *other end* of that relationship.

Comment: It's not. It's a one-way street that goes in the opposite direction of what it seems like you mean by **dependency.** If this is not so, then your question is very unclear. Right the business with "Foo" and "Bar" sounds like "Bar" requires "Foo" in order for "Bar" to happen/exist. In that case, "Foo" *is* a prerequisite for "Bar." I think you need to eliminate the FOO/BAR wording and use relatable, meaningful concepts.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. I don't know how to put it clearer: “BAR has a *dependency* on FOO” means that in order for BAR to happen/exist, FOO is a condition that must be satisfied. So it seems you are presenting a synonym of that.

Comment: Since this answer was written, OP has actually used the word *prerequisite* in the question. If "*bar* has *foo* as a prerequisite", then *foo* is a prerequisite of/for *bar* (rather than the other way round, as in this answer). It's unusual for a clarifying edit to completely reverse a question like that.

Comment: I think part of the hangup might be that role of BAR/FOO got switched in the answer vs. the original question.   If BAR depends on FOO, then FOO is a prerequisite for BAR, makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'independent' is best here. 'Foo is independent of bar, Bar is a dependent on Foo.'

Dependent is a noun as well as a verb, and could work well here. 'Bar is a dependent of Foo.'

Note: in the US, dependent is both an adjective and a verb. In England (until recently) dependent was an adjective and dependant was a noun. Today it is acceptable in both countries to spell the noun without the 'a'.

The suggestion you provided I don't think works "Foo is a dependency of Bar"

Dependency is the relationship between two things. 'The child's dependency on his parents..." The child is not a dependency, The relationship is.

Comment: I take your point about the role “dependency” plays. I have corrected the question to clarify.

Comment: Does 'independent' not work?  FOO is independent of BAR, but BAR is dependent on FOO.

Comment: @J.Elek independent is different.  It just states that FOO is not dependent on BAR.  FOO would still be independent of BAR even if BAR never depended on FOO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with [contribute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contribute) or contributor.

> FOO is a contributor to BAR.
>
> FOO contributes to BAR.

I believe every dependent is reliant upon whatever is contributed in a dependency relationship.  Dependents do not supply that need, but a contributor does.

While contribution doesn't necessarily mean the receiver of the contribution is dependent upon the contributor, in a dependent relationship, the contributor is the only one providing what is needed for the relationship to exist.

Comment: Thanks. The sense of “depended-on” does not fit “contribute”; I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

`BAR has a dependency on FOO` can be denoted by interchanging the positions of FOO & BAR as:

> FOO has an ***impact*** on BAR.

ODO:

> **[impact](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impact)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **2** A marked effect or influence:
>
> ‘The introduction of these foreign organisms can have a devastating
>   impact on marine environments.’

The above example could have been:

> Marine environments have a dependency on introduction of these foreign organisms.

Comment: Thanks. The sense of “depended on” does not fit “has an impact”; I have updated the question.