# Inverse of dependency

Tags: single-word-requests, subject-verb-inversion

In a project management context where A and B would be tasks, if A needs B, then B is a dependency of A. Is there a word to describe what A is to B?

As @KateGregory put it, I want to replace "we need to get B done, a lot of things are depending on it" to "we need to get B done, it has a lot of X" where X is the word I'm looking for.

I'm talking about the English concept, not the logical implication, though they're clearly related. Predecessor / successor is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, you just used it.  "needs"

Comment: No, "needs" is still B. I want A.

Comment: More context would help.   Is it about politics?

Comment: Unless this is to be used in a very restricted domain, there is no word.  For example put `A=human` and `B=oxygen`.  Then `A` needs `B`, but oxygen really couldn't care anything about humans.

Comment: @Centaurus Question edited accordingly.

Comment: to clarify, you want to replace "we need to get B done, a lot of things are depending on it" to "we need to get B done, it has a lot of X" where X is the word you're looking for?

Comment: @KateGregory Exactly.

Comment: Ok, that's a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/what-is-the-correct-word-for-dependee but the context is slightly different.

Answer (score 5):

As discussed in [What is the correct word for "dependee"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/what-is-the-correct-word-for-dependee): The dependent depends on the dependency.

> we need to get B done, it has a lot of **dependents**.

Here are some more phrases which mean the same as each other:

- A (the dependent) depends on B (the dependency)
- A requires B
- A is made available by B
- A is an opportunity from B

- B is a prerequisite of A
- B blocks A
- B allows A

Comment: It sounds ambiguous to me (non-native English-speaker), but I admit this is the closest I could get.

Comment: Over in US, we use the term "dependents" once a year when filing taxes.  There is a different tax policy that applies when you have a different number of dependents (people that depend on your income).