# Word for opposite of *prerequisite*? Something that is possible because of another thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

***Prerequisite*** describes something that must exist before another thing. Is there a word that describes an opposite, that is, **something that is made possible because of the existence of another thing?**

For example, in [Carl Sagan's famous quote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Carl_Sagan) "If you wish to make an apple pie from scratch, you must first invent the universe", *inventing the universe* is a prerequisite of *making an apple pie from scratch*. Is there a word that works when we switch those two subjects: *making an apple pie from scratch* is a(n) ______ of *inventing the universe*?

I know that I can rephrase the sentence, or use multiple words to express the meaning, for example, "*making an apple pie* is **one of the things I can do after** *inventing the universe*". I can also use a made up word like *postrequisite* (although that exact example may not fit, as I understand it means something that *must* be done afterwards). I would like to know if there is one word, that is used widely, that means the same.

Comment: Wouldn't the opposite be something that is then made *impossible*? These are still prerequisites. *Enabled*?

Comment: @Mazura There are many different ways to construct opposites, or antonyms. I agree "opposite" is imprecise, so I provided some examples. Another "opposite" to prerequisite is the made-up postrequisite (something that must be done afterwards).

Comment: Ah, I got ya. I have a personalized Windows disk. It has an extra folder called *run.it.after* (stuff that cleans up the install).

Comment: Precursor would work here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about **dependency**?

> **de·pend·ence** *n.* **4.** The state of being conditional or contingent on something, as through a natural or logical sequence. “The dependency of an effect upon a cause.”
>
> —[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/dependence) (cf. Random House Unabridged Dictionary)

Or, comparing the respective definitions found in Webster’s 2nd:

> **pre·req·ui·site** (prē·rĕkʹwĭ·zĭt), *adj.* Required before; necessary as a preliminary to a proposed effect or end; essential as a condition precedent. *n.* **1.** Something required beforehand; something necessary to an end or effect; a condition precedent; as, the *prerequisites* of freedom. …
>
> **de·pendʹen·cy** (dē·pĕnʹdĕn·sĭ), *n.* **1.** State of being dependent. = DEPENDENCE, 4, 5. **2.** That which depends; that which is attached to something else as its consequence, subordinate, annex, etc. **de·pendʹence** (dē·pĕnʹdĕns), *n.* … **4.** State of being influenced and determined by, or of being conditional upon, or necessitated by, something else; as, the relation of an effect to its cause is one of *dependence.* **5.** State of depending, or being subject; specif., subjection to the direction or disposal of another or others; inability to … provide for oneself; …

Comment: Do you mean *dependant* instead? *Dependency* is often used to express the inverse relationship, i.e. A is a dependency of B, B is a dependant of A.

Comment: @congusbongus - From a linguistical point of view, the dependency is the state of being dependent. However, in computer science, the word often describes an A-B relationship, without a clear identification of which is the prerequisite.

Comment: @congusbongus: I think you have jumped the gun on accepting this answer. And I'm honestly surprised it has the most upvotes, given the number of programmers who also frequent this site. Your comment can be strengthened from "often" to "almost exclusively", at least in computing. *Dependency* is in fact used interchangeably with *prerequisite* when talking about software requirements.

Comment: I agree this is backwards. "the x of y" means "y's x". "The dependency *of* an effect" means the effect *has* the dependency of its cause. The cause *is* a dependency of its effect. You can substitute the word "prerequisite" without changing its meaning.

Comment: I think dependency and dependant are both backwards. The word [dependee](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25575/what-is-the-correct-word-for-dependee) would fit, if it were a real word.

Comment: Those coming across this answer who have exposure to the field of computer programming or software development should be aware that the way in which the word “dependency” is often employed within those circles is largely peculiar to that field: using the word “dependenc(y|ies)” to describe “The thing(s) that my thing *depends* upon” constitutes occupational jargon at best and *utterly bass-ackwards employment* at worst. **For general audiences, this answer is correct.** The dissension it has received likely comes from software folks surprised to find they may have been misusing the word. :-P

Comment: As an aside, I sometimes wonder how many who live in the U.S. and work in software have ever tried to file their own taxes in lieu of hiring a service. Those that have will have known what sense the word “dependency” bears outside of their *niche.* As a programmer myself, I have taken to replacing (mis)usages of “dependency” in code and documentation whenever I come across them with the objectively less ambiguous “prerequisite”. In the broader scope of things, “dependency” seems to me to be well on its way to becoming the next “bi-weekly”: a word rendered less than useful by double-meaning…

Answer (score 7):

You could consider using a "possible outcome". [**Outcome**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/outcome) means:

> The way a thing turns out; a consequence: '*it is the outcome of the vote that counts*'

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Your example:

> Making an apple pie from scratch is a possible outcome (one of possible outcomes) of inventing the
>   universe.

Comment: This is as close as it gets, I think, with some synonyms: *possible outcome*, *potential result*, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think a strict opposite of pre-requisite exists in English but considering **pre-requisites** and **preconditions** are [synonymous](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/topics/importance/important-and-essential-things/),  how about ***[postcondition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcondition)***?

> In computer programming, a ***postcondition*** is a condition or predicate that must always be true just after the execution of some section of code or after an operation in a formal specification. Postconditions are sometimes tested using assertions within the code itself. Often, postconditions are simply included in the documentation of the affected section of code.

[Wikipedia]

Although it is primarily a computer term, it may fit your sentence well, if you offer it some flexibility.

> Making an apple pie from scratch is a ***postcondition*** of inventing the Universe.

It tends to imply that "*if* the Universe is created, the apple pie *must* be made from scratch."

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=postcondition&year_start=1950&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpostcondition%3B%2Cc0) indicate that it is a fairly popular term since the late 1970s.

Comment: I don't think this is the same. With the OP, we're not saying apple pies must exist in any universe. We're just saying an apple pie can't exist without the universe first existing. A postcondition says kind of the opposite: an apple pie might exist without a universe, but the presence of a universe necessarily means there are apple pies. *universe -> pie* instead of *pie -> universe*.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is a *widely used* word that means what you want. For maximum clarity and unambiguousness, just use a phrase.

If you absolutely must use a single word, you could try **enablement**:

[From [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Enablement):]

> n.  1.  The act of enabling, or the state of being enabled; ability.

This word does have established uses other than your intended meaning, but if you craft your sentence carefully, you may be able to provide enough context for the reader to get what you mean.

Comment: "Enablement" is nice as a complement to "requirement" (which is in turn a synonym of "prerequisite"). Thus, "A is an enablement of B" if and only if "B is a requirement of A".

Answer (score 3):

#### Presuppose

> (of an action, process, or argument) require as a precondition of possibility or coherence.
>
> "his relationships did not permit the degree of self-revelation that true intimacy presupposes"
>
> synonyms:  require, necessitate, imply, entail, mean, involve, assume
>
> "this presupposes the existence of a policy-making group"
>
> - [source](https://www.google.com/search?q=presuppose+definition&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS604US604&oq=presuppose+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.6082j0j8&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8&hl=en-US)

---

Other possibilities include:

- requires
- necessitates
- entails

Use any of the options below (followed by on/upon) to describe something made possible by something else:

- contingent
- dependent
- conditional

Comment: I think this is a strong fit.  Making an apple pie from scratch presupposes inventing the universe.

Comment: +1 for *contingent* which leads to  *is contingent on/upon* in OP's case.

Answer (score 2):

Use the root word of *prerequisite*, **require**.

> Making an apple pie **requires** (first) inventing the universe.

You could also just use *prerequisite* in a wordier fashion:

> Making an apple pie **has the prerequisite of** inventing the universe.

Alternately, "only possible" or "can only be accomplished" would make sense here.

> Making an apple pie is **only possible after** inventing the universe.
>   Making an apple pie **can only be accomplished after** inventing the universe.

<sup><sub>Random note: for some reason, trying to quickly type "apple pie" constantly results in "applie pie". Brains are weird.</sub></sup>

Comment: The OP looks for exactly the opposite, so your answer is not useful.

Comment: @rexkogitans: The OP asks how to say making apple pie is possible because of the invention of the universe. If inventing the universe *is* a requirement, then making an apple pie *has* that requirement, or *requires* said invention. It may not be the best possible word choice, but it does exactly what is asked for.

Comment: Oops, forget about my comment... sorry... I upvote it...

Answer (score 2):

Corollary

from Wiktionary: something which occurs a fortiori, as a result of another effort without significant additional effort.
Finally getting that cracked window fixed was a nice corollary of redoing the whole storefont.

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing is sometimes called a *postrequisite* or *post-requisite* of the thing(s) it depends on. In [DITA](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/cs01/spec/archSpec/dita_generic_task_topic.html), for example, a post-requisite (element [`<postreq>`](https://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.1/OS/langspec/langref/postreq.html)) "*describes steps or tasks that the user should do after the successful completion of the current task*." (But in some DITA contexts I think it is understood more as things that the user *can* do, not necessarily things that the user *should* do.)

But this word is essentially newly coined, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I agree that *postrequisite*, like the similarly non-standard *prepone*, can be easily understood, but I'd prefer something that is used more widely, something more standard. Besides, it has a slightly different meaning - "that which is required to be done after" - than what I want.

Comment: Why don't programmers call it *dependent*?

Comment: @congusbongus: My understanding is that a *postrequisite* is **not** something that is **required** to be done after, in the sense that it is required. It is something that can only be done after its prerequisite, but it is not necessarily required (mandatory). In this it is not exactly a mirror of *prerequisite*.  IOW, *postrequisite* is precisely what you said in your question: "*one of the things I* ***can*** *do after*" - the operative word being *can*, not *must*.

Comment: This smells like the elusive COMEFROM command that never made it into Radio Shack BASIC. In my admittedly limited experience, many programmers have been accused of using English, but actual convictions have been infrequent.  Grmpf.  ;-).

Comment: It's possible that some people use *postrequisite* to imply *can*, rather than *should* or *must*, but this is definitely uncommon. If you Google for *postrequisite*, you will see that most people take it to mean something that isn't optional.

Answer (score 0):

The word ***consequence*** fits nicely into the reversed Sagan quotation.  You could also try *sequel* for this particular context.

Since ***prerequisite*** can also suit up and play as an adjective, an appropriate opposite number could be ***attributable***.

Comment: I disagree that *consequence* fits nicely. If B is a consequence of A, that means B *necessarily follows* from A. The question is: what's a word that means B **can** follow from A.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of think the word **byproduct** works in the scenario you paint. It's not precisely what you describe, but definition #2 I think is awfully close.

by·prod·uct | ˈbīˌprädəkt | noun | 1.  something that is produced during the production or destruction of something else.  2. something that happens as a result of something else.

Answer (score 0):

Grammaticus

Use antonyms for prerequisite:
1optional, 2unnecessary, 3voluntary, 4inessential

A and B are possibilities and/or 1234.

A is 1234 to/for B.

A need not be 1234 to B. [can be or not be by choice]

I also had this thought:

You want 
- A is, hence B.
Eg. "I have a digestive system, hence I can eat".

To be the opposite of 
- A is, thus B.
Eg. "I am hungry, thus I must eat".

Comment: Hi, Grammaticus, do you think **optional** or others would fit in the blank of the Original Poster's example sentence? We need a noun, not an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

**Product Of  or Derived From**

This implies a connection between the two but maybe that forms the requisite.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the terms from mathematical logic: necessary condition and sufficient condition. The following statements would both be correct and both say the same thing:

Inventing the universe is a **necessary condition** for making an apple pie from scratch.

Making an apple pie from scratch is a **sufficient condition** for inventing the universe.

What that last statement is saying in other words is: if you have indeed made an apple pie from scratch, then this is sufficient information to know that that you have also invented the universe.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency

Answer (score 0):

In software, the terms that relate to your question are preconditions and postconditions. Meaning those things that are true before (upon entry to a procedure) and those things that are true after (upon exit from a procedure).

Answer (score -1):

[Successor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/successor%20?s=t): a person or thing that succeeds or follows.