# antonym of pre-requisite

Tags: antonyms

must steps required before a particular tasks are called pre-requisite

what do we call must steps which should be followed after a particular task

post-requisite is not a valid English word i guess , is there replacement ??

Comment: Related: [Word for opposite of *prerequisite*? Something that is possible because of another thing?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307436/word-for-opposite-of-prerequisite-something-that-is-possible-because-of-anoth)

Comment: I think it's usually just referred to as "the next step".

Answer (score 1):

The English language is fairly flexible, so long as you follow certain rules. I'm fairly sure that very few people would have a problem with you using the word "post-requisite" so long as A: it serves a useful purpose and B: it's not for a Scrabble game.

Comment: It also helps that in this particular case the similarly-constructed word, "pre-requisite" is in common usage.